# Multithreading using C++ and Pro*C

Tags: c++, oracle

We want to write a multi-threading application using `C++` and `Pro*c`. I have written classes for spawning the threads and doing business logic. I am facing an issue while connecting to the database using `Pro*C`.

I don't see any way to write `Pro*C` code to get the SQL context back to the `C++` layer and assign it to a thread. I searched google for examples and I see the entire threading logic being embedded in the `Pro*`C layer.

I am trying to code like below.

```
void getSqlContext(const char* userName, const char* password)
{
/*
  declaring the variables.
  sql_context ctx1;
*/
  /*Enabling threads in proc.
  opening a connection
  */
 /*
  returning sql_context
 */
}
```

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Why can't you just return it from the function?

Comment: Pro*C is little bit different, there is no interface functions like OCI to get the connection back to c++ code